# How philosophers reason about closeness of one theory to the other theory (approximation, learnability, discovery of theory)?

Tags: epistemology, scientific-method, formal-theory, theory, measurement-theory

Some theory is tuple of set of axioms (including ones that are statements about data), set of inference rules and set of already deduced theorems (statements) in it. Theory can be discovered by human being by lengthy and partially informal process. But theory can also be learned by neural networks. There are true but unknown theories and there are known theories that approximate the unknown ones to some degrees. There is reasoning with degrees of truth.

My question is - is there some philosophical, epistemic, gnoseological know that measures how much one theory is close to another theory, some kind of distance among theories? Of course, different aspects can be measured (complexity, expressivity, number of statements with the same truth value of both theories) and that is why different measures can exist. I am not seeking the ultimate list of such aspects and measures. I am just seeking the common name, term, keyword that is used in the philosophy to describe the efforts to research the closeness of theories.

Comment: Judging by the first sentence, you have in mind formal theories. For those the question of proximity is meaningless until one is interpreted in the other (or both in a third), see [interpretability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability). With that in place, see [Friend et al., Distances between formal theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01501) for a framework for measuring proximity. This research is recent, even equivalence of theories is a very complex and unsettled subject.

Comment: Thanks! It is OK, if research is nascent only. I am seeking the entry points.

Comment: I understand thar every informal theory ultimately can be represented by some kind of probabilistic, fuzzy or adaptable logic theory, so there is not so much distinction from formal (crisp, certain) theory.

Comment: It is not about vague vs crisp. Empirical theories include heuristics and procedures that operationally connect them to their subject matter and allow for interpretation, revision, testing, etc. None of that can be captured linguistically because it involves performing actions and interpreting their outcomes. Informal (linguistic) theory lifted from that is only a shadow of the original, and even more so when formalized. Different empirical theories can conceptualize events "incommensurably" and then even the preliminary inter-interpretation process becomes problematic.

Comment: @Conifold It is very interesting that you are saying about "empirical theories". Can you, please, name, some books or philosophers who try to conceptualize the epistemic process of building, comparing (or even maybe machine-learninge) such empirical theories? I am aware of journal https://informallogic.ca/index.php/informal_logic and maybe it is the venue of research of such empirical theories? I still think that this process can be formalized, i.e., there is not only the formal semantics of natural language, but also discourse theory and pragmatics and such...

Comment: ... (formalized) pragmatics together with formal semantics of natural language can be the tools for formal capture of informal/empirical theories as well. Artificial intelligence must and will have to handle and do informal/empirical reasoning as well that is why I am seeking the philosophical research on such kind of reasoning with the aim to formalized and operationalize it for the use by Artificial (General) Intelligence.

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics and discourse representation theory. See also AI about commonsense reasoning and knowledge and even about the motoric/visual intelligence.

Comment: Sorry about my requests about empirical theories - this is deviation from the original question. Your link to the distance article (published in Bulleting of Symbolic Logic) is the answer I sought, many thanks!.

Comment: Consider special relativity and Lorentz's theory of ether. They are formally equivalent, there is a translation that preserves all theorems, but people take them as very different theories. Whatever distinguishes them will not be captured by formal distance, it is lost in translation. Intuitively, they assign different "meanings" to the symbols involved. What "meaning" is is notoriously difficult to pinpoint, but it includes operational aspects that are not captured by symbols and axioms for manipulating them.

Comment: Artificial intelligence may be able to handle it if it is equipped with operational capabilities but that will not erase the difference between them and linguistic representation. No representation can *do* the representing itself required for concept specification and interpretation of events. On incommensurability of theories see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incommensurability/) and references there. In particular, it discusses semantic view of theories that does not conceptualize them as linguistic entities and perhaps can capture more of the empirical originals.